# lower triangular matrix

Tags: matrices

Our current course discusses the following topics:

- row echelon form
- elementary matrices
- linear equations
- vector spaces and sub spaces

In one exercise there is a square matrix A given :

$$A=
 \begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 & -2 \\
3 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We should find a invertible matrix B so that BA=C and C is a lower triangular matrix.

It seems to me that this couldn't be possible because the row reduced form of the given matrix will be:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am confused and I am looking for some hints

Comment: ok it's no problem to solve this. for some reason i assumed the pivot elements of the triangular matrix must be != 0 and that's wrong

Comment: $$SA=B$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1  \\ 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -2 & -2 \end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix} -4 & -2 & -2  \\ 3 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -2 & -2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0  \\ 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

a lower triangular matrix means $1 < i < j \le n$:

$a_{12}=a_{a_13}=a_{23}=0$

I've found a invertible matrix S so that SA=B and B is a lower triangular matrix. What do you think about it ?